# Save, merge sometimes doesn't commit ? Why?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello i have a problem with Java Hibernate,
I have an Entity called 'Barang' and i have a function to create new Barang or update it.
Sometimes it works fine, but when i tried doing it again and again, the function isnt working.

Here's my code for create and merge :

```
static SessionFactory session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

public Session opennSession(){
   return session.openSession();
}

public void addBarang(Barang b) {
    Session sess = this.opennSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction t = sess.beginTransaction();
    sess.save(b);
    t.commit();

}


public void updateBarang(Barang b) {
    Session sess = this.opennSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction t = sess.beginTransaction();
    sess.merge(b);
    t.commit();

}
```

What makes it more confusing is, i have another entity that works perfectly fine with save or merge function. I have compared it so many times, and i sure that the code is fine.

Please help me fix this.
Thx in advance

If you need some code that im using, i can post it here.
So please tell me if you need it. :D

Here is my hibernate.cfg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD     3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rumah</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
    <mapping class="entity.Pelanggan"/>
    <mapping class="entity.Penjualan"/>
    <mapping class="entity.PenjualanBarang"/>
    <mapping class="entity.PenjualanBarangPK"/>
    <mapping class="entity.Barang"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if there's any justification for doing your merge inside the transaction, since there's nothing else happening, so in fact it's a one-operation transaction.

I'd suggest you try flushing your session and see if it helps:

```
sess.merge(b);
sess.flush();
```

Comment: Hi maksimov, thx for your suggestion.
I tried using flush(), but it didnt work.
Thx anyway :D